# WMS without GetCapabilities in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

How can I add a WMS source that does not support GetCapabilities request in QGIS? This source can be opened in, for example, Openlayers, that does not require GetCapabilities but how do I show it in QGIS? I guess a custom GetCapabilities xml-file is needed, but how do I add it?

Comment: It should be possible to reverse engineer the GetCapabilities XML file and put it into your own server. Take some existing document as a template http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities, and point the GetMap onlineresource links where you want `<DCPType> <HTTP> <Get> <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"  xlink:href="http://demo.geo-solutions.it:80/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&"/>
</Get> </HTTP> </DCPType>`

Comment: If it doesn't support `GetCapabilities` it isn't a WMS

Comment: You might need to use PyQGIS I guess. The last code block in the section https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers

Comment: @etrimaille: your doc is so 2.*x* ! This link is better (IMHO ;) ) even if the API doesn't change since for this part : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers

Comment: Indeed, sorry. Blame some search engine :) The header "outdated version" is only visible at the top of the pahe. https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers for automatic "latest" ;-)

Comment: >but QGIS does not change its GetMap request accordingly. This is a different question however but please drop a line if you know the answer. Add "SERVICE=WMS&amp;FORMAT=image/png&amp;TRANSPARENT=TRUE" to GetMap key OnlineResource.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out easier than I thought. I downloaded a GetCapabilites xml-document, changed the obvious parameters such as URL, BBOX, CRS and then imported it using "Import raster" in QGIS. So that's a nice workaround if "Add WMS layer" does not work due to server not fulfilling the WMS standard.

Unfortunately the background is white and I seem to have no control over the GetMap request that QGIS sends regarding FORMAT and TRANSPARENT. I would like to add "FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE" but don't know how. I have tried to add this in the xml in several places...

```
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <Transparent>true</Transparent>
```

but QGIS does not change its GetMap request accordingly. This is a different question however but please drop a line if you know the answer.