# Add raster layer from WMS service

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, wms

I am trying to add Raster layer from WMS to QGIS map using Python.
I can open the raster image in the browser,
but when I try to add it to the map in QGIS I get an error  "Layer data source could not be found"

Note: the service has GetCapabilities but it is hidden

[image]

URL that works in the browser and displays the raster image correctly:

http://.../wms?service=WMS&layers=test&format=image/jpeg&srs=EPSG:3765&style=&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&bbox=179915.796253907,4894451.95071427,291816.250020064,5006352.40448043&layers=test&width=256&height=256&IgnoreGetFeatureInfoUrl=1&

But when I try to add raster layer from WMS to the map in QGIS it's not working, here is example:

```
uri='url=http://.../wms?service=WMS&layers=test&format=image/jpeg&srs=EPSG:3765&style=&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&bbox=179915.796253907,4894451.95071427,291816.250020064,5006352.40448043&layers=test&width=256&height=256&IgnoreGetFeatureInfoUrl=1&'

    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "test", "wms")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(raster_layer, False)
    self.root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    self.root.insertLayer(0, raster_layer)
```

Is it possible to ignore or block GetCapabilities request?

Comment: This seems to be a similar question (and answer): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414820/wms-without-getcapabilities-in-qgis

Comment: If the service doesn't support GetCapabilities requests it isn't a WMS.

Comment: When you load a WMS into QGIS it reads the GetCapabilities response to understand the layer names, supported operations, CRS, formats and styles etc.

Comment: @nmtoken It support getCapabilities but its hidden. Is it possible to skip reading the getcapabilities, basause all of that information I provide in URI (getmap request)

Comment: QGIS needs the GetCapabilities response.  You can't use the GetMap request because it doesn't give all the required information, and additionally because QGIS will add its request parameters to the URL you give as the base URL risking duplicated parameter values.